# Problems calling a shared object created from a C file while in production

Tags: c, heroku, shared-libraries

I am trying to call a shared library object "libexample.so", but Heroku can't find it. I even set the library path to the directory where the shared object is located, but nothing changed. It works locally, but when I deploy it I get: "Error opening shared object "libexample.so":libexample.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."

Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting us to guess as to what you have actually implemented.  How was it linked?  does the deployed system actually contain that library?   Suggest making a 'static' application so all necessary library functions are already contained in the executable ==OR== assure the desired library is in the library path of the deployed system

Comment: Yes, I do have the shared object deployed. I am able to call the C function using Python.  It's when I try to deploy it with Common Lisp that it breaks. I'll have to consult the Common Lispers for this problem. Thank you for trying to help.